# BigQuery - COUNTIF Unixtimestamp meets event_date in YYYYMMDD format?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working with Google Analytics App plus Web data in BigQuery.
I want to count a user AS new_user WHEN user_first_touch_timestamp value matchs the table's event date value. This would result in a a count of new users who visited the site on a particular day.
Example value in user_first_touch_timestamp
1595912758378962
Example value in event_date
20200809
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You should parse both values t same DATE type - as below

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) AS event_date_day
```

and

```
DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) AS user_first_touch_timestamp_day
```

After this is done  - now you can do whatever comparison you need

For example - if you want to use it in WHERE clause - it can look like below

```
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) = DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp))
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. When I try to run the new query, I get this error: Unrecognized name: event_date_day; Did you mean event_date? at [7:7]. I'm trying to use WHERE value in one field = value in another field                                                
SELECT
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) AS event_date_day,
DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) AS user_first_touch_timestamp_day,
COUNT (DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS new_users,
FROM `project-table`
WHERE event_date_day = user_first_touch_timestamp_day

Comment: see addition in the answer